# Extension install callback not called for Firefox

Tags: javascript, callback, firefox-addon

I'm actually adding a button on a website to install a web extension and I would like to have a callback telling me if it was successfull or not.

I came accross [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InstallTrigger/install) showing this code to do so :

```
function xpinstallCallback(url, status)
{
if (status == 0)
   msg = "XPInstall Test:   PASSED\n";
else
   msg = "XPInstall Test:   FAILED\n";
   dump(msg);
   alert(msg);
}
xpi={'XPInstall Pre-Checkin Test':'pre_checkin.xpi'};
InstallTrigger.install(xpi,xpinstallCallback);
```

So I built my code using this model and some information I gathered around the net and here is my code :

```
$("#install-firefox").on('click', '.install-firefox-extension', function() {
    var params = {
        "Extension": { URL: "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/example/example.xpi",
            IconURL: 'https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addon_icons/example/example.png',
            Hash: "sha256:30097adeeadcf2683e9a4aexampleaa82403aafb7faa6db9f44db657a786a4",
            toString: "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/example/example.xpi"
        }
    };
    InstallTrigger.install(params, function(url, status) {
        if (status == 0)
            console.log("Extension successfully installed");
        else 
            console.log("Extension failed");
    });
});
```

The installation work, my problem here is not entering the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MDN documentation for `InstallTrigger.install()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InstallTrigger/install) states:

> In Firefox 3 the callback is no longer invoked unless the website performing the installation is whitelisted.

Given the wording, this means that in Firefox versions >= 3 the callback function is never called unless the website from which the installation is initiated is whitelisted. It is highly unlikely that your website is whitelisted, thus the callback function will not be called. Other than requesting Mozilla to whitelist your website (I would consider this to be *very* unlikely), there is nothing you can do to get the callback executed just from the invocation of `InstallTrigger.install()`.

The alternative, assuming you have control of the code for the extension, is for the extension to notify the website that it's been installed. How to do this will depend on the type of extension which you are installing. Presumably, it will be a WebExtension. If so, there are a few methods: `window.postMessage()`, a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent), or have the extension execute an already existing function/set a variable in the page context.